# Creating rectangular polygon grid with even spacing between research plots in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, agriculture, research

I am trying to create rectangular plots with even spacing, between research plots, in QGIS. If it were a commercial field, with no spacing between plots, I use the "Create Grid" tools on Vector > Research Tools. I need to draw 2000 rectangular grids on the field. Therefore, creating then manually and duplicating them will take too much time.

Is there a way to add spacing (vertical and horizontal) to the grids created on this tool? Is there an additional tool or plugin that can accomplish such task?

QGIS version: QGIS 3.22.3 'Białowieża' on Windows 10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Create a point grid with a wider spacing than 40*50 m
2. Rectangles, ovals, diamonds. Rectangles with a width and height 40*50

[image]